# 3D manipulator not pointing in the right direction

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I'm having hard time positioning a vertex properly because the manipulator direction changes depending on what vertex I select.

[image: front view] I'm in the front view, but Y axis (green) is pointing at bottom-right.

[image: different vertex selected]
Here it's pointing at bottom-left, isn't Y-axis supposed to be pointing down and/or up no matter which vertex I select?

[image: another different vertex selected] 
Yet again, the Y-axis (green) is pointing down/up correctly and so the others, which is what I want.

How do I make the manipulator x,y, & z axis points in the right direction no matter which vertex I select?

I've tried these, but no luck:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*
- load factory settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientation of the 3D manipulator is determined by the setting of the **Transformation Orientation** control in the bottom of the 3D view.

[image: transform orientation setting]

You have set it to *Normal* which aligns the manipulator to the vertex normal. You might want to set it to *Global* or *Local*.